# Recursive function to generate multidimensional array from Doctrine database result on oneToMany Category entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, categories

I don't find any suitable answer for my need,
in fact,
I have an entity Category and it has self relationship as **[One-To-Many, Self-referencing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)**

I need to generate a multidiamention named value array like 
Sample Array:

```
Array
(
    [Disaster] => Disaster
    [Disaster_sub] => Array
        (
            [Natural] => Natural
            [War] => War
        )

    [Techno] => Techno
    [Tecno_sub] => Array
        (
            [IT] => IT
            [IT_sub] => Array
            (
                 [Dev] => Dev
                 [Bizz] => Bizz
            )
        )

)
```

What I actually tried out is

```
public function generateCategoryTree($entity, $arr = [])
{
            $children = $entity->getChildren();
            $parent = $entity->getParent();
            $name = $entity->getName();

            if(is_null($parent)) {
                $parentName = $entity->getName();
                $arr[$parentName] = $parentName;
            }

            if(!is_null($children)) {
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $list[$name] = [$name => $name];
                    $this->generateCategoryTree($child, $arr);
                }
            }

        return $arr;
}
```

And then in an another function I call it,

```
$queryCategory = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c')
                    ->from('CategoryBundle:Category', 'c')
                    ->where('c.parent IS NULL')
                    ->orderBy('c.root, c.lft',  'ASC');

        $entities = $queryCategory->getQuery()->getResult();

        $choices = [];

        foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
             $choices += $this->generateCategoryTree($entity, $choices));
       }
```

I am just nearby but not achieved,
any help?

Comment: http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/tree.html

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this is not what i was expecting, still I've used this Gedmo extension to generate my Category Entity, and now what I want is to create a multidimensional array from the db result and to use it in a custom form choice type.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, for those who is having the same problem,
 here is the working code
**Note:**
The entity *Category* here having the properties and getter setter according to [Gedmo DoctrineExtensions](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/tree.html)

```
public function generateCategoryTree($entity, &$arr = [])
{
    $children = $entity->getChildren();
    $name = $entity->getName();
    $arr += [(string)$entity => $entity->getId()];

    if(count($children) > 0) {
        $arr[$name.'_sub'] = [];
        foreach($children as $child) {
            $this->generateCategoryTree($child, $arr[$name.'_sub']);
        } 
    } 

    return $arr;
}
```

And the i call this function here,

```
$choices = [];

    foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
        $this->generateCategoryTree($entity, $choices);
    }
```